# run php code on user logout in joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, logout

Version - Joomla 3.6.2

My package includes one admin component, one frontend component and one module.

I am trying to run some php code(http request) on user logout.  I am confused about where to write that code. 
I have few questions -

- I am unable to find the good resource on implentation of events . How to use these events (https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)
- Do i need to write a plugin for this ???

Comment: Looks like you need to put this in a plugin.

Comment: @apokryfos i am not sure about this option , a plugin file just for one small feature .  in drupal hooks are used , in wordpress there are filters , there should be another way to do this ?

Comment: In drupal, any user code is technically part of a module or theme, which is sort of a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, writing a user plugin is what you want, and it is pretty simple. Below is a skeleton for you to start with:

- Make a new folder in your installation, ex /plugin/user/yourplugin
- Add an xml-file: yourplugin.xml with the following content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0.0" type="plugin" group="user" method="upgrade">
  <name>plg_user_yourplugin</name>
  <author>NeiL</author>
  <creationDate>Aug 2017</creationDate>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <description>Add a description</description>
  <files>
    <filename plugin="yourplugin">yourplugin.php</filename>
  </files>
</extension>`

- And a php-file like

`<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class PlgUserYourplugin extends JPlugin
{
  function onUserLogout($credentials, $options){
    // call whatever php you like here...
    return true; 
  }
}`

The docs say onUserLogout should return a boolean, but returning false does not seem to have an effect, user is still logs the user out.

If the plugin should only run on the frontend, you need to handle this.

You can use the discover - functionality (Extensions->manage->discover) to install the plugin after you create the files. Remember to enable the plugin after installing.

Comment: Hi,  I have one question in mind , Suppose i am making a extension ,  other customers will install my extension via zip package,  If i go with this method , i created a folder name plg_myExtension , then i used your method . Do admin have to enable plugin mannually from backend ??? or is there a method to auto enable that plugin ???

Comment: Hi NeiL, I can see that it is possible to auto-enable plugins on install if you also write an install-script for your component. I have not done this myself, but there seems to be some answers if you try to google it.

Comment: This solves the problem , I copied the onUserLogout function from /plugin/user/joomla/joomla.php file , and put my code in between it.  I hope i am doing it right .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this either using `plugin` or doing template overriding of login module & com_user component where you can set a custom url on logout. Therefore, after logout process is complete user will come to your custom script and you can do your stuff.
Or, if you don't want to keep updating joomla, you can hack com_users.

**Note : Only Plugin method is recommended which is more secure & proper way of achieving what your goal.**